# Load .ser file which is inside my project explorer

Tags: java

### Load .ser file which is inside my project explorer

---

I've been working around with file paths and Serialization and all is well, however with my current code my file path was simply the file name ("Students.ser") which would obviously save the files outside the project which isn't too good(unorganized).

I've been searching and trying to mess about the file paths to get the current path **inside** my project in order to keep the collections here.

---

> Here's a more graphical idea of what I'm trying to say:
>   [image: Current project layout]

---

I don't want to hardcore the entire path as that is just an easy way around what I'm trying to do, I simply want it to create the file within the project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *read* the files, just use

```
this.getClass()
    .getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("jdatabase/collections/students.ser")
```

And use the provided stream to deserialize your objects.